# php mysql how to use mysql_insert_id() to be able to insert into 2 table at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I am using php with mysql database to do some insert.
I have 2 tables.

- user
- status
  where the second table has as foreign key user_id  to relate between these 2 tables

my problem is that when i insert into status table the user_id field do change and take 0 no matter what is the user_id.

so how to fix this problem ???

## this is the code of login.php

```
<?php
//array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if(empty($_POST['user']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
       $response["success"] = 0;
       $response["message"] = "enter Both Fields";
        // echoing JSON response
        die (json_encode($response));


}

else if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password']) ) {

    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    // include db connect class
    require_once '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $sql = mysql_query("Select user, password from users where user='$user'")or die(mysql_error());
    $count_query = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if($count_query >0){
     $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "correct Informations";

   // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
     else{
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Wrong User Or Pass";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}   
?>
```

## status.php

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();
if(empty($_POST['status'])){
       $response["success"] = 0;
       $response["message"] = "You must Write something";
        // echoing JSON response
        die (json_encode($response));
}

// check for required fields
else if (isset($_POST['status'])) {

    $status = $_POST['status'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();



    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO status(status, user_id) VALUES('$status' , '$last_insert_id')") or die(mysql_error);
    $last_insert_id = mysql_insert_id();

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Your Status has been saved.";

        // echoing JSON response
        die (json_encode($response));
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        die (json_encode($response));
    }

}

?>
```

**i am using php with android so their is no html form**

Comment: your '$last_insert_id' is not set to anything prior to calling mysql_query()?

Comment: so how to solve this  and get the value of user_id field added to the database???

Comment: if this is about logging in, you could place the user ID in a cookie so you can use it anywhere in your application

Comment: how to place the userID in a cookie and use it in android ??

Comment: I'm not familiar with running PHP in Android, but I guess you should be able to create some kind of session, as @Marc B said in his answer.  That's what I meant by using a cookie.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `mysql_insert_id()` only applies to the **LAST** insert performed. If you're doing two inserts, and call insert_id() after the second one, the first ID is lost.

There is no way around this.

You must have something like:

```
INSERT INTO foo ....
$fooid = mysql_insert_id();
INSERT INTO bar .... foo_id=$fooid
$barid = mysql_insert_id();
```

Given that your code actually seems to be split into multiple pages, it's even worse. mysql_insert_id() only applies to the CURRENT connection to the database. Once your first script exits, the connection is closed and the insert_id is lost.

The next script will get a NEW connection, and have its own completely separate insert_id system going.

For chaining multiple pages together like this, you'll have to retrieve/pass the insert ID around yourself, e.g.

page1:

```
INSERT ...
$_SESSION['page1_id'] = mysql_insert_id();
```

page2:

```
$last_id = $_SESSION['page1_id'];
INSERT ..... id=$last_id
```

Comment: so what you say  that i must create $_SESSION in the php file in the first page than retrieve this session as an foreign key in the second table that is used in the second page ??

Comment: "The first ID is lost" only when you perform 2 queries. If you make bulk insert `values (...), (...)', you can calculate next id by adding +1 to the id, which will be the id of the first record of bulk insert.